# How to add the same thing to every row in a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Im not sure why I cant find this online but I simply want to tell a query to have a new column which is the same thing for every row.

So something like this:

```
ID    Pollo  
001    True
002   False
003    True
004   False
005    True
```

And I wanna make it this where I add a variable called Tag and it is strictly the word "Mark" for every row:

```
ID    Pollo  Tag  
001    True   Mark
002   False   Mark
003    True   Mark
004   False   Mark
005    True   Mark
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a constant expression as a column in a query's select-list, and an expression can be a simple value:

```
SELECT ID, Pollo, 'Mark' AS Tag
FROM mytable;
```

Since this value is a constant, it will be the same on every row returned by the query.

You should assign the column an alias by using the `AS` keyword. This becomes the header for the column.

The data type for the column is implied by the expression. In this case, it's a varchar.

Comment: thank you bro, this was so simple and strictly all i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the data to the table:

```
alter table yourmysterytablename add column Tag varchar(desiredmaximumlength);
update yourmysterytablename set Tag='Mark';
```

If you just want to add it to your select results:

```
select ID, Pollo, 'Mark' as Tag
from yourmysterytablename
where ...
```